# kafka connect error while loading debezium plugin " Unable to instantiate"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am installing a basic kafka 3.6.1 on a VM.
I tried loading the debezium plugin but got the errors:

```
ERROR Failed to discover Transformation in /home/ec2-user/debezium-connector-sqlserver/debezium-core-2.4.1.Final.jar: Unable to instantiate TimezoneConverter: Plugin class has a dependency which is missing or invalid (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.ReflectionScanner:138)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException

[2023-12-14 19:37:10,229] ERROR Failed to discover Transformation in /home/ec2-user/debezium-connector-sqlserver/debezium-core-2.4.1.Final.jar: Unable to instantiate EventRouter: Failed to invoke plugin constructor (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.ReflectionScanner:138)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

[2023-12-14 19:37:10,254] ERROR Failed to discover Transformation in /home/ec2-user/debezium-connector-sqlserver/debezium-core-2.4.1.Final.jar: Unable to instantiate ComputePartition: Plugin class has a dependency which is missing or invalid (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.ReflectionScanner:138)

[2023-12-14 19:37:10,263] ERROR Failed to discover Transformation in /home/ec2-user/debezium-connector-sqlserver/debezium-core-2.4.1.Final.jar: Unable to instantiate ActivateTracingSpan: Plugin class has a dependency which is missing or invalid (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.ReflectionScanner:138)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
```

cat config/connect-standalone.properties|grep -v ^#

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/home/ec2-user/debezium-connector-sqlserver/
```

Is there anything else I should do before loading the debezium plugin?

Comment: Hi there, I having the exactly same issue as yours.
Did you find any solution for this?